# Simple_form, edit multiple associated items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to edit multiple association in a single form. I'm using simple form and my association is easy:

```
Class Gallery
 has_many :pictures
end

Class Pictures
end
```

Every picture has an image and the caption, but I have already uploaded all the pictures in a separated form: I need now to add the caption text for every picture in a single form.

I try with simple_form doing this:

```
 = simple_form_for [:admin, gallery] do |form|
    - if gallery.pictures.present?
        - gallery.pictures.each do |p|     
            = image_tag(p.image.url(:thumb), height: '50')
```

but I cannot find a way to add the caption text field for every picture of my gallery.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method `simple_fields_for` for nested resources

example:

```
simple_form_for [:admin, @gallery] do |f|
  f.simple_fields_for :pictures do |p|
    # Here you have all simple_form methods available
    p.input :caption
  end
end
```

Also, add this line to `Gallery` class

```
#this allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
```

Update - show small thumb inside form for each picture

```
image_tag(p.object.image.url(:thumb), height: '50')
```

Comment: I try with your solution and it works, except that I cannot find now a way to show the object (so the small thumb) near every text area input.

Comment: You can access picture object inside form with `p.object`.